# How to implement INSERT where not exists for ORACLE in Mule4

Tags: sql-insert, oracle12c, mule4

I am trying to implement a use-case in Mule4 where a tour needs to be assigned to a user if it has not already been assigned.

I was hoping that I could implement it using Mule db:insert component and using INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS SQL script as below.

```
INSERT INTO TL_MAPPING_TOUR(TOURNO,TLID,SYSTEM) select :tourno,:tlid,:system from DUAL 
where not exists(select * from TL_MAPPING_TOUR where (TOURNO=:tourno and TLID=:tlid and SYSTEM=:system))
```

However, this is resulting in Mule Exception

```
Message               : ORA-01722: invalid number
Error type            : DB:BAD_SQL_SYNTAX
```

TL_MAPPING_TOUR table has an **id** column (Primary Key), but that is auto-generated by a sequence.

The same script, modified for running directly in SQL developer, as shown below, is working fine.

```
INSERT into TL_MAPPING_TOUR(TOURNO,TLID,SYSTEM) 
select 'CLLO001474','123456789','AS400' 
from DUAL 
where not exists(select * from TL_MAPPING_TOUR where (TOURNO='CLLO001474' and TLID='123456789' and SYSTEM='AS400'));
```

Clearly Mule db:insert component doesn't like the syntax, but it's not very clear to me what is wrong here. I can't find any INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS example implementation for the Mule4 Database component either.

stackoverflow page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910330/insert-record-into-sql-server-when-it-does-not-already-exist-using-mule directs to page not found.

Any idea what is wrong here and how to implement this in Mule4 without using another Mule4 db:select component before db:insert?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "mule4", but this:

> Message               : ORA-01722: invalid number

doesn't mean that syntax is wrong (as you already tested it - the same statement works OK in another tool).

> **Cause**: You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful.
>
> **Resolution**:
>
> The option(s) to resolve this Oracle error are:
>
> **Option #1**: Only numeric fields or character fields that contain numeric values can be used in arithmetic operations. Make sure that all expressions evaluate to numbers.
>
> **Option #2**: If you are adding or subtracting from dates, make sure that you added/substracted a numeric value from the date.

In other words, it seems that one of columns is declared as NUMBER, while you passed something that is a *string*. Oracle performed implicit conversion when you tested the statement in SQL Developer, but it seems that mule4 didn't and hence the error.

The most obvious cause (based on what you posted) is putting `'123456789'` into `TLID` as other values are obviously strings. Therefore, pass `123456789` (a number, no single quotes around it) and see what happens. Should work.

Comment: TLID datatype is actually VARCHAR2 so it should take a string, and that is why it runs fine in SQL developer.

Comment: Then the culprit is something else; Oracle usually doesn't lie when it says that there's an INVALID NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is too forgiving. It will convert string to numbers and vise versa automatically when it can. And it can a lot.
Mulesoft DB connector tries the same but it is not as succefule as native tools. Pretty often it fails to convert, especially on dates but this is not your case.
In short - do not trust too much data sense of Mulesoft. If it works - great! Otherwise try to eliminate any intelligence from it and do all conversions in the query and better from the string. Usually number works fine but if doesn't - use [to_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) function to mark properly that this is the number.

More about this is here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/AvoidCoversionsOrMakeThemNative.html